# Java code alternative for netcat to run Flink example SocketTextStreamWordCount

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am trying to run `SocketTextStreamWordCount` but on Windows. I am not able to find *netcat*, those which are available on net are somehow getting rejected by my antivirus.
How can I write a basic Java code to push data to this Flink program.
I tried [EchoServer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html) and EchoClient examples to push the data but that also seems to be not working. Can anyone help me with this problem ?

Comment: Your question is nor related to Flink per se. You ask for support to sent data to a socket in Window. I woudl recommend to rephrase this question and tag differently. (or switch to Linux ;) -- btw, *netcat*  is a Linux tool, so you will not find it on windows. Furthermore, for testing purpose, why not shut down your anti-virus program?

Answer (score 1):

1. Run the below java code, to start a server with port `5000` which sends text `Hi` in a infinite loop.
2. Then Start your Flink Client (`SocketTextStreamWordCount` Program) with `5000` port.

Your Flink Server would now be able to print the word count for `Hi`

*Code:*

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    try
    {
        int port = 5000;
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Server started");

        System.out.println("Waiting for a client ...");

        socket = server.accept();
        System.out.println("Client accepted");

        while(true) {
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
            bw.write("Hi\n");
            bw.flush();
            System.out.println("Sending Hi");
        }

    }
    catch(IOException i)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are lots of things wrong with this code. Streams and other resources should be wrapped in try with resources syntax to avoid possible leaks. A while (true) is generally dangerous

Comment: Yes, this code was written was only for quick testing.

Answer (score 0):

Installed https://nmap.org/ and that seems to have worked .